# How do I Display Data from an API in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Overview:**

I am trying to use React to display data from an API. I have the "building blocks" of what I need, but I am trying to figure out how to combine them.

**Problem:**

I have a page that gets Rendered, a fetch call that requests data from an API, and some code that loops through the returned object.

How do I combine these three things so that I can see the content rendered on the page?

Thanks!

**Here is my React code:**

```
import { ... } from "...";

const Index = () => (
  <Page>
    <Frame>
      // HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO LOOP THROUGH THE API RESULTS
    </Frame>
  </Page>
);

export default Index;
```

**Here is how I fetch data from an API:**

```
function getDataFromApi() {
  var url = "api.example.com";
  return fetch(url, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  })
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseData) => {
    return responseData;
  })
  .catch((error) => console.warn(error));
}
```

**Here is how I'm looping through an object:**

```
var i;

for (i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) { 
  var object = objects[i]
  console.log(object);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the endpoint when the component gets rendered, but only the first time, if additional renders happen you usually don't want to keep calling the API.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

const Index = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getDataFromApi() // <--- call your API on the first render only
  }, []);

  return (
  <Page>
    <Frame>
      // HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO LOOP THROUGH THE API RESULTS
    </Frame>
  </Page>
  );
}

export default Index;
```

The hook `useEffect` runs whenever one of the dependencies changes, in this case there are cero dependencies, therefore this hook will only run once! How do you know there are no dependencies?

```
useEffect(() => {
   // Your code
}, []); //<---- These are your dependencies, the array is empty, therefore no dependencies for this hook.
```

The second thing is to store the API response somewhere, we usually use the local state, but you can use a library such as redux, mobox, or something else to store the data, in this example I'm going to use the local state.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Index = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]); // <--- Initialize the state with an empty array
  useEffect(() => {
    getDataFromApi()
      .then((response) => setData(response)); // <---- Set the data to the local state
  }, []);

  return (
  <Page>
    <Frame>
      // HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO LOOP THROUGH THE API RESULTS
    </Frame>
  </Page>
  );
}
```

First you need to initialize the local state by using the `useState` hook. The, after the server response you need to set the response to the local state so you can use it on your component.

```
return (
  <Page>
    <Frame>
      { data.map((item) =>
         <p key={item.id}>{item.name}</p>
       )}
    </Frame>
  </Page>
  );
```

Given that `data` is an array, whenever the API responds the data gets assigned to the local state and then using `map` you can loop the array and render a paragraph or any other component for each item.

You need to make sure to set a `key` to each element in the loop, this tells react to mount/unmount component if the key changes, among other things.

Good luck!